# Pre loading csv files with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with flask to build a web app and there are several bits in python code where I need to load a csv file.

```
with open('{}/src/public/file.csv'.format(current_app.config['PROJECT_ROOT']), 'r') as f:
    rows = csv.readlines(f)
```

Then I go on to use `rows` to do some calculations.

My problem is that I'd rather not do this every time a user triggers the request. I'd rather have this loaded when I start Flask, and have `rows` accessible to the python code within the request.

Naturally, my first try was to take it out of the python function and put it at the start of my views.py file but that raises an app context error.

How do I achieve what I am after?

NB: I'm not familiar with the terms thread, stack, context (but willing to learn).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen your whole code so not sure if it can help. But usually when you have app context problems in flask you need to use this:

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
# All other imports go here
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    with open('{}/src/public/file.csv'.format(current_app.config['PROJECT_ROOT']), 'r') as f:
    rows = csv.readlines(f)
```

Comment: In this case it would be sufficient to use `app.config` directly instead of using `current_app.config` within the application context.

Comment: does this not create a new application instance? I don't know why that would be bad but something tells me it is (correct me if I'm wrong). I was thinking more about doing it when the first app instance was created, I just don't know which stage to do it at.
PS it worked. I just had to do the extra step of importing the config file first.

Comment: `app = Flask(__name__)` is supposed to show the initialization of your Flask app. Try to use `with app.app_context()': in your app and see if it helps.

Comment: It does work. But not if I remove the line `app = Flask(__name__)`, because that's originally in a separate file. I suppose I could import it somehow?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I don't how your is structured. It's difficult to say now.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Just add the line to your file containing the app initialization and import it in the module you need it.

Comment: @MrLeeh would that not just cause the line to initialize another app instance anyway? If I have a py file with var = func() and then I import var to another file, that runs func.

Comment: Not if you use the factory pattern.

Comment: As @Nurzhan already wrote it is difficult to say without your application structure at hand.